# Full load product in magento

Tags: php, magento, product, getproperties

On product list/grid magento already has collection of products, and get from it products using foreach.

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
...
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
```

But these products don't have all necessary properties. I'm not sure, but i thing they have no inventory data. But i need some elements of _data array.
I know only one way how to do that:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

Is there any another way, how to reload product properties?

Comment: Hi, Can you please specify the list of data you need  ?

Comment: If I look at _data array before load($_product->getId() - i will see 27 values.
When i make load - I will see more than 45. I need to get property of custom value, which is placed by 3rd party extension.

Comment: Is it a custom product attribute (By the 3rd party extension) ?

Comment: I'm afraid that this will only complicate the question. For example lets get product QTY. It also doesn't exist in the described product collection. (As by default magento it doesn't need on the product grid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need some data in the product list, edit the attribute in the backend and set the field "Used in product listing" to `Yes`.
Save it and rebuild your indexes.

There is also the option of loading the product inside the `foreach` loop but this can lead to performance issues.